# How do I create a folder structure in Linux?

Tags: shell-script

I have a scenario where I want to create a folder structure like the one below. How can I write a `for` loop in such way that it would create this structure:

```
ABC [Parent folder]
   -> A1 [child folder]
   -> B1 [child folder]
   -> C1 [child folder]
   -> W1 [child folder]
   -> W2 [child folder]
   -> W3 [child folder]
   -> V1 [child folder]
   -> V2 [child folder]
   -> V3 [child folder]
```

I will pass in a file like this:

```
ABC|A1|B1|C1
ABC|W1|W2|W3
ABC|V1|V2|V3
```

**Note :**

*The above file content should be taken as input and the folders should be created.*

```
#ABC - MAIN PARENT DIRECTORY
#REMAINING AFTER ABC are child folders
```

Answer (score 11):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), the canonical way :

```
while IFS='|' read -r maindir subdir1 subdir2 subdir3; do
    mkdir -p "$maindir/$subdir1" "$maindir/$subdir2" "$maindir/$subdir3"
done < file
```

### Output

```
$ tree ABC
ABC
├── A1
├── B1
├── C1
├── V1
├── V2
├── V3
├── W1
├── W2
└── W3
```

Answer (score 5):

If you trust your input file, you can convert it to a series of shell commands and run it:

```
sed 's/^/mkdir -p /;sX|X/{X;s/|/,/g;s/$/}/' file | bash
```

This turns lines such as

```
ABC|A1|B1|C1
```

into

```
mkdir -p ABC/{A1,B1,C1}
```

It works with one or more entries after the first, not just three.

Comment: Note that the `{A1,B1,C1}` thing is a bashism so it won't work in, say, `dash` as expected: it will create a directory named "ABC" and a directory literally named "{A1,B1,C1}" under it.

Comment: @kostix indeed, that’s why I’m piping to `bash` explicitly rather than `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F\| '{pdir=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {sdir=pdir"/"$i; system("mkdir -p "sdir)}}' input
```

This will run through each line in your file and set `pdir` to the first field, then it will loop through every field from 2 on and set `sdir` to `pdir/field`.  Then it uses the `system()` function to call `mkdir` with the `-p` option to create the parent directories if needed and not warn if a directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Just spit them out in one shot:

```
mkdir -p ABC/{A,B,C}1 ABC/{V,W}{1,2,3}
```

Comment: Or even `ABC/{{A,B,C}1,{V,W}{1,2,3}}` (two characters shorter) to create ***those nine directories**,*  but the question is asking how to create the directories specified *by the input.*