# How do i create main folder subfolder and file name

Tags: shell-script, directory-structure

I have a scenario where I want to create a main folder sub folder child folder and file in that child folder

my text file contain below format

```
ABC|A1|B1|A.txt
ABC|BB|CD|AF|JIDS.txt
ABC|BB|CDE|AFD|KL|JI.pdf
```

This above file need to be passed in form of for loop 
Lets take an example of first record

```
ABC|A1|B1|A.txt
```

ABC -> Main folder
A1  -> Sub folder
B1  -> Child folder
A.txt -> Is a file

This format folders should be created

```
ABC{Main folder}-->
                  |=> A1 {Subfolder}-->
                                      |=> B1 {child folder}-->
                                                             |=>A.txt {file inside child folder}
```

Comment: This is eerily reminiscent of [How do I create a folder structure in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/561250/86440)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line, change all `|`-characters to `/` to form a pathname, create the directory, create the file at the end of the pathname.

```sh
tr '|' '/' <file |
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$pathname")" &&
    touch "$pathname"
done
```

Result:

```
$ tree ABC
ABC
|-- A1
|   `-- B1
|       `-- A.txt
`-- BB
    |-- CD
    |   `-- AF
    |       `-- JIDS.txt
    `-- CDE
        `-- AFD
            `-- KL
                `-- JI.pdf

8 directories, 3 files
```

Explanation:

- The `tr` command will replace all `|`-character with `/`, and produce something like the following:

  ```
  ABC/A1/B1/A.txt
  ABC/BB/CD/AF/JIDS.txt
  ABC/BB/CDE/AFD/KL/JI.pdf
  ```
- The above output from `tr` is read, line by line, by the `while` loop. In each iteration `$pathname` will be a line from this output.
- In each iteration, `dirname "$pathname"` returns the directory part of `$pathname` (e.g. `ABC/A1/B1` for the first iteration).  This is used in a call to `mkdir -p` which creates the directories that might be missing. The `-p` option to `mkdir` creates intermediate directories.
- `touch` is used to actually create the file referenced by `$pathname` in the directory that was just created by `mkdir`.
- The `&&` between `mkdir` and `touch` ensures that we don't try to create a file in a directory that `mkdir` (for whatever reason) failed to create.

Comment: Do you prefer `dirname "$pathname"` to `${pathname##*/}`? (Admittedly, the former is easier to understand...)

Comment: @StephenKitt I generally prefer `dirname` in situations where the pathname _may_ contain a trailing `/`.  In this case I used it to make my answer easier to read and understand.

Comment: @Kusalananda  can you able to describe the code which is written … step by step what is happening …. your code work like charm for me

Comment: @jorzuyopsoenayu.com See update.